# Old version of Adwaita-dark

Tags: gui, cinnamon, gtk, theme, gtk3

Is it possible to get the old (less flat) version of the Adwaita-dark theme for use in Ubuntu 22.04 + Cinnamon?

Comment: Old ? Do you mean this one ( https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1014995/ ) ?

Comment: @MC68020 You should put it as an answer.

Comment: @ArtEze : I would rather wait for Sam to confirm and eventually expose possible compatibility problems (which become more&more likely with gtk2/3 themes). I doubt that he offers 150 credits for a simple link. Moreover… posting link-only answers is not considered good practice under U&L_SE ;-)

Comment: Thanks @MC68020 I'll take it for a spin! Hard to know for sure from their screenshot.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be a bit broken in my version (latest LTS).

Comment: Could you please tell which working but more "flat" theme you are currently using (and comparing to the "old" version) so that I can diff some files ?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS + Cinnamon 5.2.7 with Adwaita-dark. Let me know if there's a file where I can find the Adwaita-dark version in use.

Comment: Since I cannot see any current adwaita-dark theme available (from cinnamon), I wonder how you got your current adwaita-dark ? Via system-settings > Add/Remove desktop themes > Available themes online > Refresh list ? After having installed ubuntu's gnome-themes-extra package ? (https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/gnome-themes-extra)

Comment: Actually it was there already. It would have come with Ubuntu rather than Cinnamon I think. So I installed Ubuntu desktop (minimal) and then apt installed Cinnamon desktop.